# DriverInternalError in Datastax Java Driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have been using the object mapper and accessors in the Datastax-Java-Driver without issue, but for accessing one table I am getting a DriverInternalError, which according to the documentation  http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/exceptions/DriverInternalError.html

> "This should never be raised and indicates a bug (either in the driver
>   or in Cassandra).".

My Table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE buscon.billcycle (
    billcycle uuid,
    cutoffday int,
    description text,
    length int,
    period text,
    PRIMARY KEY (billcycle)
```

I have a single data row which is;

[image]

My code is as follows;

```
public BillCycle loadBillCycle(String billcycle) {
        BillCycle bc = (BillCycle) myMapper.get(billcycle)
        return bc;
    }
```

My Class is defined as

```
@Table(keyspace = "buscon", name = "billcycle")
public class BillCycle {

    @PartitionKey
    private UUID billcycle;
    private String description;
    private int cutOffDay;
    private int length;
    private String period;
// rest are simple getters & setters plus default empty constructor
}
```

When I use an accessor to return all of the rows from the table (Select * from billcycle) then this works OK.

I can also query the data OK from a cql client with no problems.

The same program can return other objects

Full stack trace is below

> 2016-08-19 13:50:19,553 ERROR - Error in
>   WebMethods:getBillCycle:com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError:
>   Unexpected exception thrown
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Unexpected
>   exception thrown
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:43)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.get(Mapper.java:429)
>           at net.kaisersmith.sis.persistence.CassandraDAO.load(CassandraDAO.java:34)
>           at net.kaisersmith.sis.Coord.loadBillCycle(Coord.java:76)
>           at net.kaisersmith.sis.WebMethods.getBillCycle(WebMethods.java:63)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.util.UUID
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.TypeCodec$AbstractUUIDCodec.serialize(TypeCodec.java:1604)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.set(AbstractData.java:530)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractData.set(AbstractData.java:516)
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement.set(BoundStatement.java:828)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.setObject(Mapper.java:258)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.access$000(Mapper.java:47)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper$7.apply(Mapper.java:395)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper$7.apply(Mapper.java:385)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1.apply(Futures.java:713)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:861)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:53)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper$4.onSuccess(Mapper.java:124)
>           at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper$4.onSuccess(Mapper.java:121)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1181)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture$1.run(Futures.java:872)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:102)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:868)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:185)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture$1.run(Futures.java:872)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.add(ExecutionList.java:101)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:170)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:868)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           ... 1 more

Comment: The main reason is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID`

Comment: @Jens you are right, I should have converted to UUID before sending to the mapper.  (A simple error, in my other methods I done this!)  So this fixed the issue.   But then I would suggest that datastax driver/mapper should throw a different exception and not one that "should not occur" as it led me down the wrong path!  Thanks.  If you convert this to an answer then I will accept it.